# Setting (Dynamic) String Equal to Output of a Function

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, function

Is it possible to set a (dynamic) string equal to the output of a function?

Please see picture below...unfortunately, I'm not able to get it to work using the method shown here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code *is* actually working, but you need to make your `simulator()` function **return** the dataframe it makes. It *prints* it, but it doesn't return it:

Change the code for your `simulator` function to this:

```
def simulator():
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,size=(4, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
    return df  # instead of print(df)
```